# Can I implemenet do-while condition using Until-Successful message processor in Mule ESB?

Tags: mule

Can I implemenet do-while condition using Until-Successful message processor in Mule ESB ?
I want to repeatedly call outbound:endpoint until the response parameter returns expected vaule i.e. while condition will be checking response vaule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfect use case for the Until-Successful message processor.

Comment: So does it mean I can use message.payload.getName() in the "failureExpression" of Until-Processor and it will work ? I am looking at clean way to check the condition .

Comment: It depends on the type of the payload, but assuming that `getName()` is a valid method on it, yes, you can use `message.payload.name` in the `failureExpression`.